# Is it possible to change NavigationView's settings item's icon and text?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

Basically when using NavigationView, the settings item always shows up as a gear icon and a text of "Settings". Is it possible to change these two things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can edit the default template of the control to modify the style of the settings area. You can find the following there:

```
<NavigationViewItem x:Name="SettingsNavPaneItem" Grid.Row="5">
    <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        <SymbolIcon Symbol="Setting"/>
    </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
</NavigationViewItem>
```

So changing the icon is easy. Regarding the text you may be able to change it here as well, but I am not sure if the control will not override it and can't verify as I'm not at my PC. Try to use the `SettingsItem` property of the `NavigationView` and cast to `NavigationViewItem`.

### Update: Changing the text

Here is how you can customize the settings item text, I don't know why I haven't thought about it before - create a custom `NavigationView` and update the text manually in `OnApplyTemplate`:

```
public class CustomizableNavigationView : NavigationView
{
    protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
    {
        base.OnApplyTemplate();
        var settingsItem = (NavigationViewItem)GetTemplateChild("SettingsNavPaneItem");
        settingsItem.Content = "Custom text";
    }
}
```

### Update: WinUI

Going forward, the recommended solution will be to use the [WinUI library and its `NavigationView` control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview). This allows you to add multiple `NavigatoinItem` in the `PaneFooter` area and those are fully configurable. In addition to this the new control supports not only classic hamburger menu display but also can display horizontally on top of the view, which is now the recommended navigation pattern on large screens.

Comment: Using```<NavigationViewItem.Content>
                                                <TextBlock />
                                            </NavigationViewItem.Content>``` doesn't work, you were right. What you mean by your last sentence, can you give more detail of that?

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice your comment. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: I still have no idea for how to change the text :(

Comment: I have updated my answer with WinUI library `NavigationView`

Comment: @Xinpeng I know it is long overdue, but I have updated my answer with a proper solution for changing the text as well :-) !

Answer (score 5):

This is how I changed the text:

```
private void Navigation_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var settings = (Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.NavigationViewItem) Navigation.SettingsItem;
    settings.Content = "Other settings";
}
```

Navigation is my control `<NavigationView x:Name="Navigation" />` in XAML.

Comment: Without `x:Name` solution: `var navigation = (NavigationView)sender;
var settings = (NavigationViewItem)navigation.SettingsItem;`

Answer (score 2):

My answer is based on @Andreas Fredriksson answer, but contains the Icon change as well:

```
private void Navigation_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
      var settings = (NavigationViewItem)Navigation.SettingsItem;
      settings.Content = "Help";
      settings.Icon = new SymbolIcon((Symbol)0xE897); 
}
```